# Emailng-list based on query beeing updated automaticcaly from that query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

i have emailing-list(based on some params) being automatically updated from an existing query. I explain : I have an emailing list (containing only email addresses) called "new users list" that will automaticcaly be updated whenever there are new users. I assume this is going to be done by a query stocked somewhere!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [postInsert()](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_sub_the_event_listener) listener in your User model to automatically insert the new user's email to the email addresses whenever a new user is added.

Comment: thanks Qais, actually what you said works, but only in this case(new users).Unfortunatelly there are more complex lists (such as "users that have more than 2 rented cars", "users with more thant 10 comments per day") you see?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what is your question. is it how emailing list is being updated?.
if your question is how that emailing list is being updated than it can be a trigger on the table where new users being register.

Comment: but sometimes i need a list that is updated based on several tables and parameters! what do you think of a procedure ?

Comment: i think you should create triggers on every table. which you used to generate your Emailing List Table.